# Easiest way to brew an espresso in the office?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso, ground-coffee

In our office we only have an automated espresso machine that makes capuccinos, lattes etc. and of course they all taste awful. It's fully automated, so there's no way to use your own coffee with it.

I wanted to find a way to be able to brew my own coffee at the office so that I can just bring my ground coffee with me and make an awesome cup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably closest to an espresso is an [AeroPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroPress), which is similar to a [French press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press), but uses manual pressure to extract more aromatic componds while being lower on bitter and sour notes than most other methods.

And of course all the "hand filter" varieties of the drip-family can be an option, if it's simply *coffee*, not exactly *espresso* you are after.

In any case you'll need a source of freshly boiled water, e.g. an electric kettle and - important for some offices - the permit to use it.

Of course a good cleaning of the office machine, adjusting it properly and filling it with good beans might be also a step in the right direction... (And have you checked - many machines *do* have a little hidden "door" or similar where you can use your own (ground) coffee.)

Comment: If you do not have access to boiling water, a microwave oven can be a life saver. I the microwave at work to top up the temperature of the coffee machine's slightly too cold hot water tap.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you would call it an espresso but a [french press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press) would let you bring you own coffee.  That is what I use.

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?

Comment: I also fail to see anything objectionable about this answer and upvoted. Since the problem is not self-evident a comment would help.